# ServiceStack MQ server shutdown does not wait for worker background threads to complete

Tags: servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack MQ (ServiceStack.Aws.Sqs.SqsMqServer v4.0.54).
I'm running MQ server inside a Windows Service.

**My Goal:**
  When the Windows service is about to shutdown, I would like to
  wait for all running workers to finish processing and then terminate
  the MqServer.

**Problem:**
  The ServiceStack MqServer (whether it's Redis/RabbitMq/Sqs) has a Stop() method. But it does not block until all workers complete their work. It merely
  pulses the background thread to stop the workers and then it returns.
  Then the Windows Service process stops, and existing workers get aborted.
  This is the link to github source code -> https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/75847c737f9c0cd9f5dd4ea3ae1113dace56cbf2/src/ServiceStack.RabbitMq/RabbitMqServer.cs#L451

**Temporary Workaround:**
  I subclass SqsMqServer, loop through the protected member 'workers' in the base class, and call Stop on each one. (in this case, this Stop() method is implemented correctly as a blocking call. It waits indefinitely until the worker is done with whatever it's currently working on).

Is my current understanding of how to shutdown the MqServer correct? Is this a bug or something I misunderstood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code for [SqsMqServer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Aws/Sqs/SqsMqServer.cs) is maintained in the [ServiceStack.Aws](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws) repository.

The [Stop() method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/6f31d01dd39e476631fdd43094f45c23c116ad88/src/ServiceStack.Aws/Sqs/BaseMqServer.cs#L292) pulses the bg thread which [StopWorkerThreads()](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/6f31d01dd39e476631fdd43094f45c23c116ad88/src/ServiceStack.Aws/Sqs/BaseMqServer.cs#L393) and that goes through and [stops all workers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/blob/6f31d01dd39e476631fdd43094f45c23c116ad88/src/ServiceStack.Aws/Sqs/BaseMqServer.cs#L324).

Comment: the problem I'm struggling with is that the Stop() method on IMessageService is not blocking. It pulses the background thread and then returns. At this point, the main thread (Windows Service before process exit) cannot know when the workers are actually stopped. The workers may still be in the middle of processing an mq message.

Comment: @xihan I've added a new `WaitForWorkersToStop()` API in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Aws/commit/36d2b9669fb13c1f2d3adbb83c18342ec41c7a3c) which polls until the MQ Status as stopped. This change is available from v4.0.57+ that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).